# Как считать раунды для игры на Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код который генерирует математическое задание и если дать правильный ответ то будет следующее задание, как сделать счетчик который бы считал сколько заданий уже было решено? Я оставлю код тут, а также вот [этот код на JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6g0fm69/)

```
<div id="problem"></div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="answer"></input>
    <script>
     function single_problem() {
     var round = 0;
        var operator = "+";
        if (Math.random() < .6) {
          operator = "&#8722;";
        }
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 10);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*(a-1) + 1);
        var c = a - b;
        if (operator == "+") {
          var top = b;
          var bottom = c;
          var result = b + c;
        } else {
          var top = a;
          var bottom = b;
          var result = a - b;
        }
         document.getElementById('problem').innerHTML = top + ' ' + operator + ' ' + bottom + '<br><br>' + result; 


           $("#answer").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
          var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
          console.log(answer);
          console.log(result);
          if(answer == result) {
          console.log('awesome!');
            single_problem();
            document.getElementById('answer').value = '';
          var game = round + 1;
          console.log(game);
          }

        }
    });

      }

      single_problem();


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов несколько

1) Глобальная переменная - просто вынести `var round = 0;` вне функции и просто увеличивать ее (определение внутри функции следует удалить т.е. то что стоит 2 строкой).

2) Можно просто добавить параметр к вашей функции `single_problem(round)`, которая бы вызвала вот так`single_problem(0)` в первый раз на 40 строке кода на jsfidle. А при правильном ответе (30 строка), вызывать снова этот метод, но с параметром `round++` т.е. `single_problem(round++)`; Этот вариант более "правильный", раз вы решили делать задачу рекурсивно

Comment: можно пример такого кода на jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wqhowpa0/